# Making a database CREATE script with QSEE

Tags: sqlite

So I am using this program QSEE and I have completed my database with it. Now when I tell it to generate the CREATE script for me, it creates it a bit differently than I am used to I guess.

The primary key is defined like this for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE movie(
    movie_ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    yadayadayada....
    CONSTRAINT  pk_movie PRIMARY KEY (movie)
);
```

But what I am used to see is that primary key is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE movie(
        movie_ID    INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        yadayadayada....
    );
```

So are both of thoes ok?  And if I use the first one, how do I define foreign key?

Comment: Both define a primary key, the first one, doesn't establish an automatically populated column though. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQLite usually, but this is just for practice. I am just creating the database and making script.

Comment: Ah, now it hit me. So if I want to make a foreign key using the first example I just define one row like this? fk1_movie_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,

Comment: First instance uses table constraint, second uses column definition for same purpose, [in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html). Foreign key definition is only attainable with table constraint.